# How to find the 3rd element using cssselector in Selenium?

Tags: html, css, xml, selenium

There are three text boxes in my web page, however I'm sending my keys into the first one using the below CSS selector. Is there a way I can send keys to my 3rd text box using the CSS selector expression?

```
FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='text']")).SendKeys("COMMISSION")
```

Comment: try `"input[type='text']:nth-child(3)"`

Comment: Thank you Omar, it throws no such element exception. I think I 'm not using the correct tag. However I see the following xpath using F12 in chrome and able to sendkeys to the text box. FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='pane1']/search-form/div/div/input")).SendKeys("Commission"). Do you have any idea how to refactor this xpath expression to be consistent in my following test runs

Answer (score 0):

To send keys to your 3rd text box using CSS selector you can use the following *Locator* :

```
FindElements(By.CssSelector("input[type='text']"))[3].SendKeys("COMMISSION")
```